# Write names into links from one row in mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a program that writes data to MySQL, but it lists all the names I need in one box in the database. I used PHP to remove the commas that separate them, but now I have to find a way to add the names to the end of the src in an image tag. So, the names (all of them in one row) are appended to the source URL. I need only one line of HTML though. Is that possible?

$namet is the result from the database (`$namet = mysql_fetch_array( $result );`)

`$res = str_replace(',','<br>',$namet['name']);` takes the commas off and puts a break there. This was on attempt to make the list look nice.

What I'm going for is to have img src="url/NAME_FROM_DB" img [had to take the brackets off], 
 So PHP fills the page with the picture for each name.

Comment: [**Use the EDIT link to include your code, attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17758495/edit)

Comment: As @Prix said, please include examples. Though if you want a function that just separates the names for you, try `explode()` in PHP.

Comment: I've made so many attempts that I don't remember half of them. I've tried foreach

Comment: You haven't even explained the problem clearly enough for someone to understand what you're trying to do. You need to show samples of your data, and what you would like the result to be. Pick one of your attempts to show the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
$namet['name'] = "name,name1,name2,name3"; 
$res = str_replace(","," ",$namet['name']);  //remove the commas and replace with space
$explodedVariable = explode(" ", $res); //explode the list into an array

//loop array values into the img tag
foreach($explodedVariable as $objects) {
    echo "<img src='images/" . $objects . "'/>";
}
```

Comment: I'm not that new to PHP. I know that. It's what is behind the variable. I used explode, now I just need to figure out how to use those results to add into the URL.

Comment: what do you mean?  "It's what is behind the variable."

Comment: what defines the variable. how do I make PHP use a long row of data EX: "name,name1,name2,name3" into single names. ex: src="images/name1 without having to make a line of HTML for each. the page is using wildcard DNS and has to be dynamic.

Comment: I appreciate your time.

Comment: Wow. I can't thank you enough. Works great. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: no prob feel free to click that checkmark beside my answer when you get a chance

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know if there is a way to do this same thing but without displaying anything would you? So the row (another one) has individual columns for these names, but I need to get a way to separate them(they don't have commas every name. It's just one long line when echoed via php). I have to check if the username they are trying to register with, is in the table the application generated. Loops... as you know aren't my thing.

Comment: what does the row output look like

Comment: I got it working. I found a way around the loop. Thank you though.